# Validate Bean in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there a way in spring boot to validate properties in a bean? For Example, consider an Employee Bean consisting of following properties -

1. id - must start with 01,02,22
2. Department - Should be any of the one - D1, D2, D3
3. Name - Must not contain any digits and max length of 10 characters.

I can have a separate method and validate the bean every time but looking for some better way to implement this using spring boot.

Comment: Take a look at JSR 380 validations.

Comment: create your  custom valdiation rule ,  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-using

Comment: You can make validation in your service to check if the Employee is ready to save or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use spring boot validation to validate your patterns.
Add this dependency to your gradle file implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation') https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation checkout the latest version

```
class Employee {

  @Pattern(regexp = "^(01|02|22).+$")
  private String id;

  @Size(max = 10)
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[^0-9]+$")
  private String name;

  @Pattern(regexp = "^D[1-3]$")
  private String department;
  
}
```

And in your request

```
@RestController
class EmployeeRequest {

  @PostMapping("/registerEmployee")
  ResponseEntity<String> registerEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("valid");
  }
}
```

Note: I am not sure about syntax of regex but you should define your regex for your business requirements.